# Java: Interactive with a Website

Tags: java, interactive

Example, I have a website with a form like this http://vnsky.biz/search/
How can I using Java to interactive with the form ?!
Include:
- Create a connection to the website.
- Post the data(song's name).
- And get the response data from server.

How can I do it with Java ?!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the URLConnection class.  You can search java's documentation to answer any of these questions. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is you can use jave.net.httpurlconnect to send a request to this server, the format is like this:
http://vnsky.biz/search/search.php?keyword=you word to search

and you will get a response which contains the search result. you may have a look at the response format and parse the link or text from the response for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This SO question can help you I think:

[Android HttpPost: how to get the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323617/android-httppost-how-to-get-the-result)

It shows both how to do an HTTP Post, using the `HttpPost` and `HttpClient` classes, among others.  These classes are a part of the [Apache HttpComponents library](http://hc.apache.org/).