# 'traces.txt': Permission denied

Tags: android, mysql, http

I have been trying out the tutorial shown on various websites on connecting a MySQL database using php to android. I dont know whats wrong with my code below. Can anyone tell me what i need to do.

**ihave this problems : Unfortunately , city has stopped**

IN LOGCAT : 01-17 02:57:18.790: E/dalvikvm(325): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied

i try chane permission but i cant because iam not root in AVD

This is my php code

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","???????????","......;");
mysql_select_db("???????????");
$sql=mysql_query("select * from users");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

city.java

```
package com.android.City;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class city extends ListActivity {

JSONArray jArray;
String result = null;
InputStream is = null;
StringBuilder sb=null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

 ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
//http post
try{
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.estm2011.org/check.php");
     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
     is = entity.getContent();
     }catch(Exception e){
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
    }
//convert response to string
try{
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
       sb = new StringBuilder();
       sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

       String line="0";
       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                      sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
              Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
//paring data
String login;
String pass;
try{
      jArray = new JSONArray(result);
      JSONObject json_data=null;
      for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
             json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
             login=json_data.getString("LOGIN");
             pass=json_data.getString("PASSWORD");
         }
      }
      catch(JSONException e1){
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No City Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.City"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".CityActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: This is not the actual problem in your program.  Your program (or possibly some unrelated program on the phone) is crashing for some other reason.  This message then occurs because of a configuration bug in the android bug reporting mechanism.  Find and fix your actual problem, and ignore this one.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line after finishing your application tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: oh ok, Here you are using InputStream, so i think might need to use setDoInput( true ) with HttpConnection.

Comment: Hi, Please look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323617/android-httppost-how-to-get-the-result  , see the answer of Sumit, There you can find setDoInput() method.

Comment: for live conversion, you are welcome here in my chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6137/

Comment: This answer is **grossly and obviously incorrect** as the referenced path is **not on the External Storage**.