# Http Client while using mobile data

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a get request to a servlet but I keep getting a time out exception, while using the mobile data connection

> java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out

When using the phone mobile data connection, I can surf the web on the browser so its not my data bundle, and the code works on the wifi connection no problem.

I tried setting the timeout to something like 1000000 milliseconds but still get the exception, can anyone help me?

here is the code I am using

```
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 1000000 );
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 1000000 );
            HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpParameters, true);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpResponse response = null;
            Log.d(TAG, "" + id[0]);


            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(
                    "http://192.168.1.10:8080/serv/request?id=" + id[0]));
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "status" + response.getStatusLine());
```

Comment: remove setSoTimeout .. it ll its own time to get a response

Comment: no that didn't change anything

Comment: remove this all HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 1000000 );
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 1000000 );
            HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpParameters, true);

Comment: I didn't have that to start with and it gave me the timeout exception that's why i added it

Comment: then change the way of performing transport.

Comment: it ll come socket exception when server doesnt get response in specified time.

Comment: go to this site http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954477/async-http-post-android and do changes according to your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your URI (`http://192.168.1.10:8080/serv/request?id=`) it looks like you are trying to access server in the local LAN.  So if your server is located in the local LAN and if it can not be accessed from the internet then you would not be able to connect to it using the mobile data connection...

Where is your server hosted? is your server accessible on internet? You need to have a static IP on your server to access the server using the mobile data connection..

Comment: I am using my computer as a JVM and my Android phone as the client.

Comment: I thought so.. To access server from mobile data connection you need to deploy you server on machine that can be accessed from internet..