# Applying a Asynctask on a HttpClient

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I haven't used an AsyncTask before neither do I understand some tutorials regarding it so I really don't know how to apply it on a HttpClient execution. Please kindly help me on this kind of implementation here's the initial code made:

```
public void commandModule(String url) {
 try {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

 } catch (Exception e) {

 }

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
    commandModule("http://192.168.1.102/?command1");
} else {
    commandModule("http://192.168.1.102/?command2");
}

if (checkBox2.isChecked()) {
    commandModule("http://192.168.1.102/?command3");
} else {
    commandModule("http://192.168.1.102/?command4");
}
```

}

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954477/async-http-post-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void commandModule(String url) {
        new RequestTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,url);

}


private class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
    protected void doInBackground(String... args){

        String url=args[0];
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the right answer just one thing, I think you should override the doInBackground.. method and API should not be less than 11 which is honeycomb.

Answer (score 1):

If you know about Thread in java, it will be easy for you to understand the working of Async Task in android. Basically, you can not perform any long running task on the main thread in android. It will block the main main thread and you will get ANR (Applicaton not responding) error. To avoid this you can either use thread or Async task. 
Thread has one limitation, you can not update UI thread form any other thread. So, to update the UI you need to send message to main/UI thread using handler. You will have to do this every time you are implementing something using thread.
To simplify, android framework provide Async Task.

So, what ever you should put in the `run()` method of Thread, should go in `doInBackground()` method.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.
check this tutorial it will give ideas about your queries http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-asynctask-example/

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

```
public void commandModule(String url) {
 try {
 new RequestTask().execute(url);

} catch (Exception e) {

}

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
commandModule("http://192.168.1.102/?command1");
} else {
commandModule("http://192.168.1.102/?command2");
}

if (checkBox2.isChecked()) {
commandModule("http://192.168.1.102/?command3");
} else {
commandModule("http://192.168.1.102/?command4");
}

}

private class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{

 @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }
protected void doInBackground(String... args){

    String url=args[0];
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}

@Override
        protected void onPostExecute() {


        }
}
```

1. onPreExecute() – Executed when execute() method is called inside commandModule() (In short When AsyncTask is triggered).
2. doInBackground() – Executed when onPreExecute() completed executing. Al the long task are handled here
3. onPostExecute() – Background job is finished