# Pass parameters Using HTTP request

Tags: android, web-services, http, parameters

Hi i am new to android programming and i would like to know how to call a web service and pass parameters to the web service to obtain the return result in form of an XML.

I previously used Ksoap lib and SOAP request but thats not working correct so now i am trying the HTTP method.

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to read up on the [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/).
Beyond that its a matter of making sure the device and server are generating messages that the other side can correctly parse.

Is the server an existing service? Or are you designing that as well?

Comment: the service is an existing one...

http://hiscentral.cuahsi.org/webservices/hiscentral.asmx?op=GetSeriesCatalogForBox2

i want to pass all the values to get the station latitude and longitude along with the location. Can u please help me with the http request?

Comment: You're going to have to do your own XML parsing to populate the XML form, and then use XML parsing to extract the information you want from the document thats returned. Beyond that its a simple matter of attaching the finished XML to the HTTP POST request. 
Though really you should be using a REST interface (it would make it a lot simpler by removing the need for the XML handling.)

Answer (score 0):

check the following in which you will use HTTP post request & you will get response in the form on XML

[Android HttpPost: how to get the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323617/android-httppost-how-to-get-the-result)