# Socket connection in android

Tags: android, sockets

In my application sending values to the server by using the code below.

```
public String sendHttpRequest(String params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    URL url;
    String result = new String();
    try {
        url = new URL(AUTHENTICATION_SERVER_ADDRESS+params);
        System.out.println("url :"+url.toString());
        HttpURLConnection connection;
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    /*PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

        out.println(params);
        out.close();*/
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("inputLine :"+inputLine);
            result = result.concat(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (result.length() == 0) {
        result = HTTP_REQUEST_FAILED;
    }
    System.out.println("Result :"+result);
    return result;
}
```

**params = ?username=*** &email=a@a.com&action=signUpUser&number=*********&password=**&port=21241**

In this method all the values are being added to the server.

But if i do the same in the below way, all the vaues is not being updated.

```
public String sendHttpRequest(String params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    URL url;
    String result = new String();
    try {
        url = new URL(AUTHENTICATION_SERVER_ADDRESS);
        System.out.println("url :"+url.toString());
        HttpURLConnection connection;
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

        out.println(params);
        out.close();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("inputLine :"+inputLine);
            result = result.concat(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (result.length() == 0) {
        result = HTTP_REQUEST_FAILED;
    }
    System.out.println("Result :"+result);
    return result;
}
```

Why it is so? Am i doing anything wrong ?

Comment: So whats your question or error ?

Comment: In the second way it is not updating all the values correctly to the server table. It is same params.

Comment: what do you mean by same params ?

Comment: params = ?username=* &email=a@a.com&action=signUpUser&number=***&password=&port=21241

Comment: In First code, you are passing values using **Get** method, and in Second method, you are passing values using **Post** method, so you need to specify the Method as **Post** when you are sending data as post.

Comment: [Post Example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2323617/2060383)