# Android HTTP POST download manager

Tags: java, android, download

In android, i have this URL to which i must do a POST request
the returned inputstream of said request returns a downloadable object...
How can I use the Android Downloadmanager itself, or a custom created one, to handle the downloading process for me?

Comment: What is your target API?

Comment: minimum suported 2.3.6
development on a 4.1 tablet, but it's mainly intended for 2.3.6

Comment: See if this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323617/android-httppost-how-to-get-the-result helps.

Comment: I had to write a seperate class to handle the download & progressbar manually, quite like the following
http://ootooban.com/en/2012/custom-download-manager-for-android-2-1-part2-resumable-downloads/

Answer (score 0):

the android's Download manager is quite simple :

```
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
Request request = new Request(Uri.parse("http://www.theeUrl.fake/image.png"));
enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
```

you can easily add parameter as its a GET request. I don't know if you can make a POST request from it.

EDIT : to make a post request you can use an HttpClient like this :

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
HttpResponse response = null;
Dictionary<String, String> postFields = new Dictionary<String, String>();  

// Set the post fields
postFields.add("username","toto")));
postFields.add("password", "thePassword45155")));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postFields, HTTP.UTF_8));

// Execute the POST request
response = client.execute(post);
```

you should be able to get an inputstream from the httpResponse to download the file.
but you'll have to manage display / notification / cancellation... yourself.

Comment: that's exactly what I knew already, that's the point, i need a POST request, not a GET request

Comment: got that  sry ;)  I'm afraid you can't use the download manager then...  i edit my post  to add another solution

Comment: I already did all that stuff :( I found the solution, well, i basicly had to create my own notification & update it myself instead of automaticly

Comment: yep... why do it have to be a POST request ? you should probably manage authentification as a separate request,  then once the session opened, use a session token in a get request to download the file ;)

Comment: i do that, but the server requires you to send along a parameter with an authenticated key before it'll serve you anything :)

Comment: Usually sessionId is use in that case, and it can be sent as GET parameter since it usually have a validity timeout server side. See what I mean ?

Comment: This server we're talking about is very secure as in, it won't accept it as a get parameter, i tried

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25475/discussion-between-jaggy-and-guian)

Answer (score 0):

http://ootooban.com/en/2012/custom-download-manager-for-android-2-1-part2-resumable-downloads/

Creating your own notification ontop of a post request, combined with a setProgress() & progressbar did the trick, so there is no conclusive way of using the DownloadManager sadly enough