# Problems with HTTP POST request for JSON object for content-type in Android

Tags: android, json, http

The following is my code for a HTTP POST request in an Android device running Android 4.1.2. I have question:

- This code works perfectly on a Samsung device whereas it is giving "Content-type is not application/json" on an HTC device.

  public static String POST(String url, JSONObject obj)
  {
      Log.i("JSONPOSTBEGIN", "Beginning of JSON POST");
      InputStream inputStream = null;
      String result = "";

  ```
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

  try {
      HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
      post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
      post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

      StringEntity se = new StringEntity(obj.toString()); 
      se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
      post.setEntity(se);

      HttpResponse httpResponse = mHhttpclient.execute(post);

      // receive response as inputStream
      inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

      // convert inputstream to string
      if(inputStream != null) {
          result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
      } else
          result = "Did not work!";
  } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
  }
  Log.i("JSONPOSTEND", "End of JSON data post methos...");
  return result;
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0):

For it to work on HTC and all devices, you must do this

```
private static HttpEntity getHttpEntity(String stringEntity) {
    HttpEntity entity = null;
    try {
        entity = new StringEntity(stringEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);
        ((StringEntity) entity).setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        ((StringEntity) entity).setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=UTF-8"));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("error creating entity: " + stringEntity);
    }
    return entity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that headers are likely being set by this

new HttpPost(url);

and that before you add new headers like for "content-type" you may have to call remove header (Content-type) first....

you need logging to figure it all out.for more on that see accepted ans [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590929/using-curl-commands-in-android/24592701#24592701)

and get WIRE & HEADER logging up in your test environment