# POST request with curl command for android using a JSON file

Tags: android, json, post, curl

I want to send a POST request with the below curl command:

```
curl -d @request.json --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=my_API_key
```

I have created a JSON file with name request.json using the below code:

```
public void CreateJSONFile(View view) throws IOException, JSONException {
 JSONObject request_hdr = new JSONObject();
 JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
 JSONArray slice = new JSONArray();
 JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

 request.put("solutions", 20);
 request.put("refundable", "false");

 JSONObject addl_info = new JSONObject();
 addl_info.put("adultCount",Num_Adult);
 addl_info.put("infantInLapCount",Num_Infant);
 addl_info.put("infantInSeatCount", 0);
 addl_info.put("childCount",0);
 addl_info.put("seniorCount", 0);
 request.put("passengers",addl_info);

 data.put("origin",Origin);
 data.put("destination",Destination);
 data.put("date", Start_Date);
 slice.put(data);
 request.put("slice",slice);

 request_hdr.put("request",request);

 text = request_hdr.toString();

 FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("request.json", MODE_PRIVATE);
 fileOutputStream.write(text.getBytes());
 fileOutputStream.close();
}
```

Now how do I trigger the POST request with the curl command using the JSON file created.
I have found couple of examples which uses Name-Value Pairs or JSON Objects. How do I use a JSON file instead of that.
Please help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: curl on android? what library are you using for that?

Comment: I am really curious why you want to do it with curl. There is a lot of easier and nicer way. Consider using retrofit/okhttp for it.

Comment: I am using the Google QPX API and for that I have to use curl commands to send requests.
I have found a similar post on this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590929/using-curl-commands-in-android

Comment: I could achieve the requirement by building this in a different way. :) Thanks for clarifying the misconception!