# Save output into two variables in Android from HTTP call

Tags: java, android, http, parsing

I saw a few posts (like this one: [Android HttpPost: how to get the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323617/android-httppost-how-to-get-the-result)) however everyone of those answers is now deprecated in mid 2016 with the latest Android and don't answer my full question.

I'm having my App do an HTTP call (**http://52.35.9.101:8080/server/keeper/login_test.jsp?username=[uniquexx]**), like this:

```
new HttpRequest().execute("http://52.35.9.101:8080/server/keeper/login_test.jsp?username=[uniquexx]");
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

which passes to an async java file called HTTP request:

```
public class HttpRequest extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    String responseString = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            responseString = out.toString();
            out.close();
        } else{
            //Closes the connection.
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        //TODO Handle problems..
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //TODO Handle problems..
    }
    return responseString;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    //Do anything with response..
}
}
```

if you put this HTTP call into the browser you'll see the server responds with the following string (two unique ID's, separated by a comma that I need to parse and save into 2 separate variables)

**5467326,8674922**

*My question is how do I save that output into a string (which I seem to be doing above) and then **parse** that string into two separate variables (x & y).*

**EDIT
-----**

```
@Override

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
super.onPostExecute(result);
String x = null;
String y = null;
String[] resultItems = result.split(",");
Log.d("tag_name", "Result IS " +resultItems);
x = resultItems[0];
Log.d("tag_name", " XXXXX IS " +x);
y = resultItems[1];
Log.d("tag_name", " YYYYY IS " +y);
```

Comment: seriously? split string and then parse ... why there are 2 upvotes ... it is a java's basic

Comment: Just a quick clarification question - so from this line `responseString = out.toString();`  you are saying the value of `responseString` is "5467326,8674922"? Please confirm. Anyway, if that is the case, then you can simply split the string into an array of two items - `items[0]` will be `5467326` and `items[1]` will be `8674922`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onPostExecute` - the value of result will be (in your example), **"5467326,8674922"** if everything went well - in that case. This is how you can split and parse the response

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    //Do anything with response..
    String x = null;
    String y = null;
    String[] resultItems = result.split(",");
    x = resultItems[0];
    y = resultItems[1];
   //now do whatever with X and Y...

}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: OK, please do and if it helps, vote and accept the answer.

Comment: for some reason I'm only able to Logprint Y but x is nothing... I also checked and the string my server is returning is actually "52.38.8.134,333333" not "5467326,8674922" , do you think the fact that it has a bunch of "." for the x is a reason to why it isn't being printed? thank you

Comment: Whatever the string is, it will split it by comma (,) - so in that case it should have printed both "52.38.8.134" for `x` and "333333" for `y`., can you please edit your question and include the updated code? I want to see the changes you have made and the log statement where you are printing the result.

Comment: I actually copied your code word for word in my HTTP request java file. I'll keep checking to see why I'm not getting the x. I print like this (Log.d("tag_name", "X IS " +x);) and same thing for y. And I get the y but for the x it is as if it is zero

Comment: Hmm so printed the "resultItem" and this is what it is ---- D/tag_name: Result IS [Ljava.lang.String;@22049bb8

Comment: Seems I need to to iterate the array and print the strings one by one and then assign them to the variables?

Comment: No, since you know you will always get two comma separated values - you can get the first item via [0] and the second via [1]. Can you show me the code where you are printing "resultItem"? Let me know so I can help you.

Comment: I just updated what I have in the "onPostExecute". On my Android Monitor x is nothing, it's not Null, its not Zero, its as if it just doesn't exist.

Comment: Very strange, could you add a log statement like this `Log.d("tag_name", "Number of Items in Result IS " +resultItems.length());` - tell us what this prints out.